# new CSSStyleDeclaration

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use the browser's built in type `CSSStyleDeclaration` to programatically pass around and modify styles (which is handy because of the `.cssText` property).

However, `new CSSStyleDeclaration()` throws an `Illegal Constructor` error. So I tried `Object.create(CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype)`, which appears to work, but the resulting object doesn't behave normally. For example, calling `.cssText` on a `CSSStyleDeclaration` created this way throws an `Illegal invocation`.

**Is there a "right" way to construct `CSSStyleDeclaration`? Or is there a better way to create styles programmatically using the built-in types?**

(I don't want to do string manipulation and I'd rather avoid making my own types or adding a 3rd party dependency.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you may create a temporary DOM element and use its `style` property:

```js
const rules = document.createElement('span').style;
rules.backgroundColor = 'red';
rules.cursor = 'pointer';
rules.color = 'white';

document.getElementById('style_string').innerHTML = rules.cssText;
document.getElementById('obj').style = rules.cssText;
```

```html
<pre id="style_string"></pre>
<div id="obj">TEST</div>
```

Comment: that way you remove existing inline-styles

Comment: @OnnovanderZee sorry, I didn't get - whose styles do you mean? Of #obj? It's introduced for demo purpose, just to show styles in action

Comment: yes, the way you assign styles to #obj, by setting the style property to the cssTxt of a style object. It works, but you can't compose the styling for #obj by copying the style.cssText from multiple elements: only the last assignment will show.

Comment: @OnnovanderZee if you want to combine - you just need to take `.style` property of a base object, extend it with composed `rules`, and then assign `.cssText`

Answer (score 5):

Like you can add/edit styles by working the properties:

```
document.querySelector("h1").style.color = '#369'
```

You can also assign the style object multiple stylerules:

```
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1")
const rules = {
    color: '#369',
    width: '100px'
}
Object.assign(h1.style, rules)
```

And then add more rules without destroying the existing inline-styles:

```
const moreRules = {
    margin: '35px',
    height: '100px'
}
Object.assign(h1.style, moreRules)
```

Proof:

```
h1.style.cssText
// "color: rgb(51, 102, 153); width: 100px; margin: 35px; height: 100px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can not create `CSSStyleDeclaration` object, But with `setProperty` method on `CSSStyleDeclaration` will make things easy and re-use the styles (as objects).

We can use hyphen-case and able to set priority as well.

```js
const applyStyles = (element, styles) => {
  Object.entries(styles).forEach(([prop, val]) => {
    const [value, pri = ""] = val.split("!");
    element.style.setProperty(prop, value, pri);
  });
};

const parent_styles = {
  "font-size": "18px",
  "font-weight": "bold",
  "background-color": "lightgrey",
  color: "red",
  padding: "10px !important",
  margin: "20px",
  width: "100px !important",
  border: "1px solid blue"
};

const child_styles = {
  "font-size": "18px",
  "background-color": "white",
  color: "green"
};

const parent = document.getElementById("parent");
const child = document.getElementById("child");

applyStyles(parent, parent_styles);
applyStyles(child, child_styles);
```

```html
<div id="parent"> 
    Hello
    <div id="child"> World </div>
</div>
```