# How to Link a CSS Object to a JavaScript Object. (In code, not in files.)

Tags: javascript, html, css

## Linking a CSS object to a JavaScript Object

### What I mean by "Linking"

Basically, I am trying to get an object in my CSS to mimic the coordinates of my object in my Javascript code. I have the javascript object being the piece everyone will see, while when I need an animation to play I make the JavaScript Object invisible, and put an identical CSS Object in its place with an animation attached to it. Then, When the animation is done, I need the CSS Object to disappear and the JavaScript Object to Reappear. If I sound like a complete idiot, I am sorry. If you have a better way to swap them or even handle the code, PLEASE LET ME KNOW. I would also like to make this all code related, and not bring outside sources/add-ons into the programs. If you need to use HTML, that works too.

TL;DR  Basically I want the CSS Object's Coordinates to mimic the JavaScripts Coordinates.

Note: The Code is just basic stuff and not from my actual game. Please take it with a grain of salt. Shape it as much as you want.

### JavaScript:

```
Box = {
        x: 20,
        y: 30,
        width: 100,
        height: 200
      }
```

### CSS:

```
#Box {
  left: 4px;
  top: 2px;

@keyframes Box {
  0%   {transform: rotate(22.5deg);}
  12.5%   {transform: rotate(33.75deg);}
  25%  {transform: rotate(45deg);}
  37.5%   {transform: rotate(56.25deg);}
  50%  {transform: rotate(67.5eg);}
  62.5%   {transform: rotate(78.75deg);}
  75%  {transform: rotate(90deg);}
  87.5%   {transform: rotate(101.25deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(135deg);}
  }
```

Comment: So you want a loading screen while your Javascript loads?

Comment: Irrelevant sentences, Please describe in clear language what you want to achieve please.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand perfectly, but :

If you have this html element :

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

Then its CSS :

```
#Box {
  left: 4px;
  top: 2px;

@keyframes Box {
  0%   {transform: rotate(22.5deg);}
  12.5%   {transform: rotate(33.75deg);}
  25%  {transform: rotate(45deg);}
  37.5%   {transform: rotate(56.25deg);}
  50%  {transform: rotate(67.5eg);}
  62.5%   {transform: rotate(78.75deg);}
  75%  {transform: rotate(90deg);}
  87.5%   {transform: rotate(101.25deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(135deg);}
  }
```

and finaly in JS

```
Box = {
    x: 20,
    y: 30,
    width: 100,
    height: 200
  };

document.getElementById('box').style.marginLeft = Box.x;
...
document.getElementById('box').addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd",function(){
   document.getElementById('box').style.marginLeft = 'initial';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about two boxes that  appears and disappears back to back , it can be done via  CSS.
Think of your animation problem as 2 boxes that move around with
varying  opacity(transparency) in the keyframe .

```css
.BOX_1{
position:absolute;
z-index:0;
animation-name: Box1;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-delay:100ms;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.BOX_2{
position:absolute;
z-index:0;
animation-name: Box2 ;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-delay:100ms;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


@keyframes Box1 {
  0%   {transform: rotate(22.5deg);opacity:0;}
  25%  {transform: rotate(45deg);opacity:0.25;}
  50%  {transform: rotate(67.5eg);opacity:0.5;}
  75%  {transform: rotate(90deg);opacity:0.75;}
  100% {transform: rotate(135deg);opacity:1;}
  }
  
  
@keyframes Box2 {
  0%   {transform: rotate(22.5deg);opacity:1;}
  25%  {transform: rotate(45deg);opacity:0.75;}
  50%  {transform: rotate(67.5eg);opacity:0.5;}
  75%  {transform: rotate(90deg);opacity:0.25;}
  100% {transform: rotate(135deg);opacity:0;}
  }
```

check out this Article on css animations [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) and tweak the properties like opacity as per your requirement
You can use JS libraries  for very complex animations

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to alter the state of your interface (HTML and CSS) with JS trickery. Luckily you have a few choices.

The JS to generate a 'box' will create HTML. Apply class styles to the HTML entity and add/remove them when required:

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: hidden;
}

.show {
   display: initial;
}
```

HTML:

```
<box id='mybox' class='show' />
```

And some basic JS to hide it:

```
$('#mybox')[0].classList.replace('show', 'hide')
```

---

But you can always just alter the target nodes `styles`:

```
var el = document.getElementById(id);
el.style.color = "red";
el.style.fontSize = "15px";
el.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
```

---

Alternatively you could just *invent* a new stylesheet:

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style')
sheet.innerHTML = "div {border: 2px solid black; background-color: blue;}";
document.body.appendChild(sheet);
```

And alter an existing stylesheet:

```
stylesheet.insertRule(".have-border { border: 1px solid black;}", 0);
```

---

It can go deeper, with manipulating the declarations of the CSS with JS.

```
var styleObj = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style;
console.log(styleObj.cssText);

for (var i = styleObj.length; i--;) {
  var nameString = styleObj[i];
  styleObj.removeProperty(nameString);
}

console.log(styleObj.cssText);
```

Which allows you to write literal elements to a single rulesheet:

```
const rules = document.createElement('span').style;
rules.backgroundColor = 'red';
rules.cursor = 'pointer';
rules.color = 'white';

document.getElementById('style_string').innerHTML = rules.cssText;
document.getElementById('obj').style = rules.cssText;
```

Or mix it up with something flavoursome:

```
const box = document.querySelector("#mybox")
const rules = {
    color: '#369',
    width: '100px',
}
Object.assign(box.style, rules)
```

---

Utilising modern CSS syntax, you can write "--vars" to your sheet, then manipulate those vars using JS:

```
:root {
  --text-color: black;
  --background-color: white;
}

body {
  color: var(--text-color);
  background: var(--background-color);
}


var bodyStyles = document.body.style;
bodyStyles.setProperty('--text-color', 'white');
bodyStyles.setProperty('--background-color', 'black');
```

---

But it doesn't stop there and you could probably find alternative methods to achieve the same result.

References and examples:

- [new CSSStyleDeclaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447958/new-cssstyledeclaration)
- https://www.toptal.com/front-end/dynamic-css-with-custom-properties
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty